# How to generate POP UP window using Microsoft Flow in Sharepoint Library

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, modern-experience, power-automate, microsoft-flow

I want to force the users to fill some required fields after uploading Document in Document Library.

I want to utilize the Power Automate to achieve this.

Whenever a user uploads document one pop up should come and ask for input for required fields/document metadata fields.

Current SharePoint version is SharePoint online and using Modern UI.

Answer (score 0):

Columns can be set to required via Library Settings. You can do this either by enabling the "Require that this column contains information" setting on the required columns or by changing the Column Settings on the content type itself. For further information, please see the article below:

https://sharepointmaven.com/how-to-make-sharepoint-metadata-columns-required/

To stop files being uploaded without the metadata being filled in first, you may need to create your own form either via Power Apps or via a SharePoint add-in.

Comment: Column is already required field and user is directly uploading document and don't care about property of Document.
Hence Document uploaded to Library but metadata/properties never updated.
I want to force the user to update metadata/properties of Uploaded Document

Comment: https://sharepointmaven.com/how-to-make-sharepoint-metadata-columns-required/

Need to prevent Scenario 2: Modern Document Library

Comment: I don't believe there is an out of the box way of stopping the file being uploaded before the metadata has been filled in. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Yes i am looking for option with Power App but not able to find any

Comment: If none of the pre-made templates (under "Start from template") suit your requirements, then you will need to create your own Power App either from blank or by starting with a pre-made template that you customise to suit your requirements.